# How to make divs sit at the bottom of another div (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, primefaces

On my website http://clothn.com/ I have this datagrid and just converted it to Bootstrap, and now that I'm not able to use table-cell, I can't get the div's to sit at the bottom of the parent.

The parent div's are

```
 <div class="ui-datagrid-column ui-grid-col-3">
```

I want the div inside of that to be placed at the bottom of it.

Div's that sit right inside the .ui-datagrid-column are like this:

```
  <div class="ui-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all product-panel bottom-aligned-text">
```

I tried to set the .ui-datagrid-column as relative and the  .ui-panel as absolute but it messes everything up and as I said, I can't use table-cell/vertical-align: bottom anymore it seems.

Can anyone tell me the CSS I need to use? All 4 "Buy from" buttons should line up on each line and the other info should stack up above it. Thank you

Still not working as of August 10th :(

Comment: _"Still not working as of August 10th :("_ it IS august 10th

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix! Just add to your anchor tag these style attributes:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
```

Comment: That only makes the buttons line up, which is part of the solution. But I want the image and product info to sit right on top of the button now.

Comment: Then add those same two attributes to the div that surrounds the product info... the one that has stuff like id="siteForm:product-table:1:j_idt118_content"

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use `position: absolute`:

Read about Bootstrap's [.panel-footer](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-footer), it may do something like you want to do in a stylish way.